# Is there a way to write regex for http2_push in nginx conf?

Tags: nginx, http2

I suppose that Nginx requires absoulte path for http_push files. But my static files names are changed after build every time. So, can I add some regex to make Nginx push all jpeg, css, etc.
I tried this:

```
    location /index.html {
       try_files $uri /index.html;
       http2_push `/*.jpeg`;
    }
```

But Nginx says: non-absolute path "`/*.jpeg`"

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Neither with regex, nor with glob pattern aka wildcard (which your question basically is).

But if you proxying (or get a response from backend by fastcgi, etc) you can do it dynamically by setting of `http2_push_preload on;` and by adding multiple `Link` preload headers to response corresponding some match (or glob pattern) you need.
See [Automatically Pushing Resources to Clients](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-9-http2-server-push/#automatic-push) for details.

Comment: Unfortunately, Nginx serves up statics on its own. Thank you for answer.